# B+ Tree Finding Number oF records

Tags: database, b-tree

Recently during my studies i came across a question like this

> What is minimum levels of B+ tree and B Tree index required for 5000 keys and order of B+ tree node (P) is 10. (Assume P is max pointer possible to store in B+ tree node)

I calculated for Btree it happens to be 4 levels . While attempting for B+ tree i ended up in a confusion . Is the order mentioned in question is internal node order or leaf node order. if it was internal node order then how is it possible to calculate Number of levels required if the order of leaf node is not known. Could some one help me ?

Answer (score 0):

You are right, the question should have mentioned the leaf node capacity.

Whatever it might be - let's call it `L` - the number of leaf nodes required is clearly `ceiling(N / L)` because the leaf node layer must contain all the data. If every leaf node can hold up to 10 records (data items) then we get a minimum leaf node count of 500. Once you have the required number of leaf nodes, you can compute the required height of the index part as usual for a B-tree.

In our case the lowest layer of internal nodes (i.e. the bottom-most layer of the index part of the B+ tree) needs to have at least 500 outgoing pointers in order to reach each leaf. `ceiling(log(500)/log(10))` is 3, which gives you the minimum number of index levels above the sequence set. Hence the B+ tree also has at least 4 levels in this case, just like the plain B-tree.